# What is wrong with the following codes? Why the graph is not shown

Tags: javascript, json, canvasjs

I am trying to come out with a line graph using canvasjs from the external JSON file. The JSON file consists of Date, high, open, low, vol and price. What is needed to show in the graph are the Date, high, open and low.

This is what I have done:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>

window.onload = function () {
    var dataPoints1 = [];
    var dataPoints2 = [];
    var dataPoints3 = [];

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
title:{
    text: "Data"
},
axisX:{
    title:"Date"
},
axisY:[{
    title: "Open",
    lineColor: "#C24642",
    tickColor: "#C24642",
    labelFontColor: "#C24642",
    titleFontColor: "#C24642"

},
{
    title: "High",
    lineColor: "#369EAD",
    tickColor: "#369EAD",
    labelFontColor: "#369EAD",
    titleFontColor: "#369EAD"
}],
axisY2: {
    title: "Low",
    lineColor: "#7F6084",
    tickColor: "#7F6084",
    labelFontColor: "#7F6084",
    titleFontColor: "#7F6084"
},
toolTip: {
    shared: true
},
legend: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    itemclick: toggleDataSeries
},
data: [{
    type: "line",
    name: "High",
    color: "#369EAD",
    showInLegend: true,
    axisYIndex: 1,
    dataPoints: dataPoints1
},
{
    type: "line",
    name: "Open",
    color: "#C24642",
    axisYIndex: 0,
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: dataPoints2
},
{
    type: "line",
    name: "Low",
    color: "#7F6084",
    axisYType: "secondary",
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: dataPoints3
}]
});

$.getJSON("q_data.json", callback); 



function callback(data) {   

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    dataPoints1.push({
        x: data[i].Date,
        y: data[i].open
    });
    dataPoints2.push({
        x: data[i].Date,
        y: data[i].high
    });
    dataPoints3.push({
        x: data[i].Date,
        y: data[i].low
    });
}
chart.render(); 
    }


function toggleDataSeries(e) {
if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
} else {
    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
}
e.chart.render();
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; max-width: 920px; margin: 0px auto;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting it to show the plotted line graph but it only shows the y-axis, x-axis and title of the graph. No error message is shown.

Comment: You're missing a closing `"` on one of your `<script>` tags.

Comment: First thing I'd do is check your browser's _Network_ console to make sure that the request to `q_data.json` worked and returned valid JSON. You could also add an error handler to `$.getJSON()`, eg `.fail((...args) => console.error(...args))`

Comment: @Santi that is my mistake while copying and arranging my codes in here.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of what `q_data.json` contains?

Comment: What else should I check? I have added an error handler to $.getJSON() and it returns success.@Phil

Comment: This is some part of the content:[{"Date":"2011-07-28","price":2.02,"open":1.98,"high":2.02,"low":1.98,"vol":67600},{"Date":"2011-07-29","price":2,"open":2.03,"high":2.03,"low":2,"vol":31300},{"Date":"2011-07-30","price":2,"open":2.03,"high":2.03,"low":2,"vol":31300},{"Date":"2011-07-31","price":2,"open":2.03,"high":2.03,"low":2,"vol":31300},{"Date":"2011-08-01","price":2,"open":2,"high":2,"low":2,"vol":101300}]</br>@Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CanvasJS supports only [number and date-time in x-values](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/x/) whereas x-value is a string in the sample JSON that you have shared. Changing it to date-object while parsing the JSON should work fine.

```js
var dataPoints1 = [];
var dataPoints2 = [];
var dataPoints3 = [];

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title:{
    text: "Data"
  },
  axisX:{
    title:"Date"
  },
  axisY:[{
    title: "Open",
    lineColor: "#C24642",
    tickColor: "#C24642",
    labelFontColor: "#C24642",
    titleFontColor: "#C24642"

  },{
    title: "High",
    lineColor: "#369EAD",
    tickColor: "#369EAD",
    labelFontColor: "#369EAD",
    titleFontColor: "#369EAD"
  }],
  axisY2: {
    title: "Low",
    lineColor: "#7F6084",
    tickColor: "#7F6084",
    labelFontColor: "#7F6084",
    titleFontColor: "#7F6084"
  },
  toolTip: {
    shared: true
  },
  legend: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    itemclick: toggleDataSeries
  },
  data: [{
    type: "line",
    name: "High",
    color: "#369EAD",
    showInLegend: true,
    axisYIndex: 1,
    dataPoints: dataPoints1
  },{
    type: "line",
    name: "Open",
    color: "#C24642",
    axisYIndex: 0,
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: dataPoints2
  },{
    type: "line",
    name: "Low",
    color: "#7F6084",
    axisYType: "secondary",
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: dataPoints3
  }]
});

$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1gfuo7", callback); 

function callback(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    dataPoints1.push({
      x: new Date(data[i].Date),
      y: data[i].open
    });
    dataPoints2.push({
      x: new Date(data[i].Date),
      y: data[i].high
    });
    dataPoints3.push({
      x: new Date(data[i].Date),
      y: data[i].low
    });
  }
  chart.render(); 
}

function toggleDataSeries(e) {
  if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
  } else {
    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
  }
  e.chart.render();
}
```

```html
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 250px; max-width: 920px; margin: 0px auto;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you are right! It works perfectly! Thank you for the help

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)